# How can you implement transfer learning with Yolov4 on colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, transfer-learning, yolov4, file-structure

I am trying to follow this tutorial for using Yolov4 with transfer learning for a new object to detect: https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2022/01/17/custom-object-detection-with-transfer-learning-with-pre-trained-yolo-v4-model/. In trying to set up the initial file structure on Colab, I'm having to guess where files and folders are needed, and could use some help in identifying if this is the right file/folder structure. Or, if there is a more detailed tutorial or a way to understand what Yolov4 is going to need, that would be great.

1. There are several references to build/darknet/x64/data/. From what I can see when I explore the two downloads, this is really /content/build/darknet/x64/data/ in Colab. Is this a correct understanding?
2. Under the data folder, is Yolov4 looking for the train folder and the valid folder? That is, is it looking for /content/build/darknet/x64/data/train/ and /content/build/darknet/x64/data/valid/? I'm guessing the answer is yes.
3. Does Yolov4 need the _darknet.labels file along with all of the image and image annotation files. I am guessing yes because this is what's in the racoon dataset.
4. The build/darknet/x64/data/train.txt and build/darknet/x64/data/valid.txt files are to have the names of the images, so I'm guessing that name includes the .jpg extension because the tutorial specifically refers to images. The reason I question this is Yolov4 should also need the annotation file names, but that is not referenced in the tutorial. If Yolov4 strips the .jpg and adds the .txt to get the annotation file name that's great, but if it needs the file name w/o the extension so that it can add the extension to access both files, then I didn't understand that from this tutorial.

Any guidance would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After working on this, here are some notes that have helped me get it to work:

- After executing `!git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/` change directories to /content/darknet before executing `!wget -P build/darknet/x64/ https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/releases/download/darknet_yolo_v3_optimal/yolov4.conv.137`.
- Although it may be obvious, to "change the Makefile to enable GPU and opencv", click on the icon on the left margin in Colab labeled "Files". In the darknet folder, open the Makefile (double click to open) and change the entries for GPU, CUDNN, and OPENCV from 0 to 1. `ctrl-s` to save the file, then `make` to compile the darknet executable.
- To get around the path names referenced in the tutorial, I used full path names. Also, since the files referenced disappear when the Colab runtime is terminated, I copied the files from folders in Drive to local folders, some of which I needed to create. Here is the code I used:

  `!mkdir /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/train`

  `!mkdir /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/valid`

  `!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/your_folder_name/obj.data /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/obj.data`

  `!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/your_folder_name/obj.names /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/obj.names`

  `!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/your_folder_name_with_train_images/* /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/train/`

  `!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/your_folder_name_with_valid_images/* /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/valid/`

  `!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/your_folder_name/train.txt /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/train.txt`

  `!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/your_folder_name/valid.txt /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/valid.txt`

  `!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/your_folder_name/yolov4_train.cfg /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/cfg/yolov4_train.cfg`
- In the folders with the images, I also included a _darknet.labels file (which just has the label for the single object you are detecting in it) and the annotation file (which has a zero in the first entry, then the bounding box coordinates using centerx, centery, width, heigth and just spaces in between--see the tutorial for an example). This was the answer for my question 3.
- The train.txt and valid.txt files in my question 4 do work with just the .jpg file names.
- The tutorial mentions that you need to change the number of filters and classes, but note this has to be changed in three locations.
- Last, if you just want the prediction to print out in Colab for an image, this can be done by modifying /content/darknet/darknet.py before doing the make. In the detect_image function, insert a `print(sorted(predictions, key=lambda x: x[1]))` before the `return`. When the make is done, this will be picked up.

If you have not copied files in Colab, it requires some permissions to be set up in your first cells. Here are the two cells I run at the beginning (Colab will ask you to manually verify you are OK with access being granted when you run the cells):

```
`from google.colab import drive
 drive.mount('/content/drive')`

`# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
 auth.authenticate_user()
 gauth = GoogleAuth()
 gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
 drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)`
```